# Crystal reports print option

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports

I want to add an option to print crystal report.I don't want to open the pdf but only show the print dialog before taking print.Any Ideas? [Ref](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms225384%28VS.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I think if you use the Crystal ActiveX Viewer you can print without the pdf.

Comment: MSDN says: Only Internet Explorer supports ActiveX controls. Printing from a non-Internet Explorer client (FireFox, Safari, Mozilla, and others) reverts to the PDF export dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the link that might help you.
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/CRPrinting10062006161454PM/CRPrinting.aspx

Comment: Thanks for reply.I have already tried this.Limitation of this method is it prints from the server itself, not from the client machine.

Comment: How do I print from client machine?